Problem connecting Expo Go to iPhone Device
I have a RN project which I have been working on for a few months on a Windows 11 machine and all of the latest react native modules installed. I have been testing on both an Android emulator and a physical iOS 17 device (iPhone 11 Max).
The EAS development builds work fine on each device. The problem resides in connecting to the iOS device. Until recently I was able to run "npx expo start" and connect to my iPhone with no issues. Now when I attempt to run the same command Expo Go states "This is taking much longer than it should..." and never connects. I have also attempted to use "npx expo start --tunnel" but I get the following message in my terminal:
This is my package.json:
"dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.2.0",
    "@expo/ngrok": "^4.1.3",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.6.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "0.5.17",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "3.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^6.4.16",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "6.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.30",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "6.2.28",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "6.6.13",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.10.0",
    "@react-navigation/routers": "6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.4.0",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "5.3.1",
    "autoprefixer": "9.8.6",
    "axios": "1.7.2",
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "1.20.2",
    "date-fns": "3.6.0",
    "eas-cli": "10.1.1",
    "expo": "~51.0.18",
    "expo-background-fetch": "^12.0.1",
    "expo-checkbox": "3.0.0",
    "expo-font": "12.0.7",
    "expo-location": "^17.0.1",
    "expo-notifications": "0.28.9",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "postcss": "8.4.39",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-moment": "1.1.3",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "1.4.0",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "4.0.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "11.1.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.16.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.14.0",
    "react-native-modal": "13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "17.1.0",
    "react-native-modals": "0.22.3",
    "react-native-paper": "5.12.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "4.0.1",
    "react-native-sse": "1.2.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.4.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "2.2.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "2.0.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "10.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "4.7.5",
    "uuid": "10.0.0",
    "zustand": "4.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  },

Any suggestions?

Maybe it's a stupid suggestion, but: Are you sure you’re logging in your terminal with your Expo account? I was having problems trying to connect to a new project and it was because of that.

There was an issue between McAfee and ngrok. I removed McAfee and used Defender and all of the problems went away. McAfee was reporting a false positive malware  on the ngrok.exe file.
